# How plot output of a clustering with different shape for clusters and different colour for the origin class?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset that includes X1, X2, and the class label. I cluster this dataset using Kmeans, and now for plotting the result I need to have points in the new cluster with the same shape; and points in the original class with the same color.

```
data = load_my_dataset() X = data.data[:, :2] # we only take the first two features. 

y = data.target kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2) kmeans.fit(X)rint(kmeans.labels_) 
df = DataFrame(dict(x1=X[:,0], x2=X[:,1], label=kmeans.labels_, target=y)) 
colors = {0:'red', 1:'blue'} markers = { 0:"o" , 1:"v" } 
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
grouped = df.groupby('label')

for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x1', y='x2', label=key, 
    color=colors[key], marker=markers[key]) pyplot.show()
```

Comment: data = load_my_dataset()
X = data.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = data.target
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(X)rint(kmeans.labels_)
df = DataFrame(dict(x1=X[:,0], x2=X[:,1], label=kmeans.labels_, target=y))
colors = {0:'red', 1:'blue'}
markers = { 0:"o" , 1:"v" }
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
grouped = df.groupby('label')
for key, group in grouped:   
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x1', y='x2', label=key, color=colors[key], marker=markers[key])
     pyplot.show()

Answer (score 0):

Set `color` and `marker` independently, rather than using the same key.

Pretty much straightforward, except that you'll need two loops and a little bit of intersection operations.